# Not displaying added two months (PHP)

Tags: php

I have a problem in my codes. Obviously, I'm beginning to program in PHP and know nothing about its advanced concepts. So I'm asking of your help. I'd like to add 2 months to the end date the user input. I tried this code below:

```
protected function inputEndDate() {
    $value = $this->endDate;
    $html = "";
    $html .= '<label for="enddate">End Date:</label>' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<input type="text" readonly name="enddate" id="enddate" value="'.$value.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="button" id="enddatebutton" onclick="getEndDate()">' . PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
}


protected function inputExpiryDate() {
    $value = $this->endDate;
    $date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime("$value +2 month"));
    $html = "";
    $html .= '<label for="expirydate">Expiry Date:</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" readonly name="expirydate" id="expirydate" value="'.$date.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="button" id="expirydatebutton" onclick="getExpiryDate()">' . PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
}
```

But when I run the program, it's not displaying the correct value; however it's displaying the added two months of its start date. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand your question.

If i call the php function inputEndDate() it renders this html for me

```
<label for="enddate">End Date:</label>
<input type="text" readonly name="enddate" id="enddate" value="">
<input type="button"     id="enddatebutton" onclick="getEndDate()">
```

The value of the input-field enddate is empty because on my code `$this->endDate` is empty.
Where do you get or fill  `$this->endDate`?

If all 3 input-fields are on the same page you need javascript to change the value of expireDate based of the input of endDate - see [my updated jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/SWQme/59/).

### Update after review of php code

I took a look into your code - i could not find the spot where you are filling the server-side php var `this->endDate`. Based on your other question [how to use change event to add dates in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798535/javascript-display-expiry-date-upon-user-input-of-start-end-date) i am unsure where the problem lies.

- If you process your php code on the server the value of expireDate must already be filled before you render the html to the client (the browser). See `public function setEditBallpark()` and the line `$this->endDate = $this->ballparkDetails->getBallparkDetailsEndDate();`
- If the page is loaded inside the browser of the client you have only html+css+javascript available. To fill the `this->endDate` you have to post the value of the client to the server (normal post or ajax). In line 17 is a comment `# $_POST["enddate"]` but the only place that may be getting the post value is this line `$this->endDate               = $this->createBallparkController->getFormEndDate();` on line 75. But the method name  `function setErrorForm()` lets me assume that this method is not relevant for the normal post case.

Comment: I fill this enddate if the user selects a specific date.

Comment: If the user fills the date on the same page than the service side generated `$this->endDate` is empty.
How is the workflow on your page / pages?
Is it something like this?
page a.html --> user selects a specific date and hits a button / 
calls a javascript function
page b.html --> this is the page where End Date and Expiry Date are being filled
You said:"it's not displaying the correct value" Could you elaborate in your question: What is the result and what should be the result?

Comment: For example, I input Oct. 9, 2012 as the start date; Oct. 16, 2012 as the end date. Then the Expiry Date should be: December 16, 2012. How can I do this? If you want to check the whole: http://codepad.org/ehDuWoQ8

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mktime()`.

[`mktime()` in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will work

```
$value = $this->endDate; // yyyy-mm-dd format
$date  = strtotime ( '+2 month' , strtotime ( $value ) ) ;
$date  = date ( 'Y/m/d' , $date);

echo $date ;
```

See the working example http://codepad.org/RM1aXXWI

Comment: I don't know what actually happened when I used your code, it displays 1970-03-01?

Comment: It's working, i checked. Your endDate might be empty. I added the working example link see it.

Comment: I think you're right about my endDate. Because I have to put first the start date, then end date. After finishing inputs, expiry date should now display...That's what I want to display. If you know how to do this please teach me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be due to $value = $this->endDate; check the $value before increasing the month count. I have checked the implementation of you adding 2 months is fine.

```
<?php
$value='2012/11/15';
$date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime("$value +2 month"));
echo $date;
```

Comment: What I want to do is, let the user fills the start and end date then display the expiry date which is the added two months to end date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime("+2 month", strtotime($value)));
```