# JavaScript display expiry date upon user input of start/end date

Tags: javascript, date

never programmed in JavaScript before, so I ask your assistance to display the expiry date when user chooses start and end date from the **calendar**. After selecting the end date from the **calendar**, the expiry date should display added two months to the end date. For example:
The user chooses Oct. 9, 2012 as Start Date; Oct. 16, 2012 as the end date; Dec. 16, 2012 should be the expiry date. How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Please check this code, cause I don't know how to edit this one.

```
/**
 * Click "Cal" on expiry date
 */
function getExpiryDate() {
if(!document.getElementById('enddate').value.length) {
    alert("End date must be set first.");
}
else {
    prevExpiryDate = document.getElementById('expirydate').value;
    displayCalendar(document.forms[0].expirydate,'yyyy/mm/dd',
        document.getElementById('expirydatebutton'));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript contains a native `Date` object, you can add months to it as follows...

```
var endDate = document.getElementById('enddate').value;
var date = new Date(endDate);
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 2); // Yes it will calculate going over a year etc
prevExpiryDate = date.getFullYear() + "/" + 
                 (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + // Months are 0 for January etc.
                 date.getDate();
```

**Note**

- The format you are inputting the value to the `Date` object is important you will want to validate this first.
- When we are creating the expiry date the value will not be prepended with zeros 2012/12/09, it will be 2012/12/9

Or you can use a library as suggested

**EDIT** updated code to make it easier to add into OP's code

**Alternative approaches**, use an event handler, I can see in your code you are using jQuery, if you are including it make the most of it...

```
$("#enddate").change(function() {
  var endDate = $(this).val();

  // Calculate expiry date
  var date = new Date(endDate);
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 2);

  // Get date parts
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var d = date.getDate();

  $("#expirydate").val(yyyy + "/" + m + "/" + d);
});
```

This needs to be run sometime after document ready, in your code line 441, and it will set the enddate field to update the expiry date field every time it is changed. If you are changing it programmatically you may need to call the change handler manually

```
// Insert value programmatically
$("#enddate").val(newValue).change();
```

Otherwise you need a way of passing through an initial value to the `displayCalendar` function, I have no details of how this function works so I cannot best advise how this might be done.

**EDIT** The function is part of DHTMLGoodies JS Calendar from 2006 which is calling onchange but doesn't play nice with jQuery so what you will need to do, is do it using the basic onchange property of the element which replaces the jQuery code above...

```
document.getElementById("enddate").onchange = function() {
  var endDate = this.value;

  // Calculate expiry date
  var date = new Date(endDate);
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 2);

  // Get date parts
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var d = date.getDate();

  document.getElementById("expirydate").value = yyyy + "/" + m + "/" + d;
}
```

Comment: Hello, how can I do it without programatically including var endDate = "2012/10/09";? Because the end date is user's input from Calendar.

Comment: In your code you have `document.getElementById('enddate').value`, I would imagine you would plug that in to replace the hardcoded value, i.e. `var endDate = document.getElementById('enddate').value;`

Comment: Tried your code, but it's not displaying anything. If you have time, please check my whole code: http://codepad.org/8lvQ61Ol

Comment: Ok yes you will need to change `var expiryDate` to `prevExpiryDate` like in your code, I have updated the answer, also here is a demo without the calendar http://jsfiddle.net/wmrvY/

Comment: Hello thanks for your patience, I really need your help here so I can solve this problem, I tried to change the code you provided for me, but when I chose the end date, expiry date is not automatically display, I need to input from the calendar :(

Comment: This is my the whole, php code: http://codepad.org/61kxTBZt and the .js code http://codepad.org/PJ4pIvyP

Comment: There are a number of approaches you could: 1. Fill the expiry date field with the calculated value when the end date field changes. 2. Get the calculated value when you click the cal button, the `displayCalendar` function isn't listed in those codepads, if it reads the input first to decide what to display then you could plug the value into the input before calling `displayCalendar`... Otherwise you would need a way of passing an initial value to it...

Comment: Thanks! The 1st approach you said is what likely would help me, give me some tips on how to do it? And there's no need for me to pass an initial value. What I need is, when the end date filed changes, it should automatically respond by adding two months.

Comment: I added your updated code after code line 441, in doing so, still, I'm not seeing the added months, I don't know what's wrong. I followed carefully through your help but it's still not showing. :(

Comment: When your calendar returns the value to the input you need to make sure the onchange event is being triggered. The `displayCalendar` function is being provided the input so you should be able to call `$(input).change();` after the value is changed in that function.

Comment: Am I doing it right this way? http://codepad.org/5UbT0owD. I added the $(input).change in getExpiryDate() function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17752/discussion-between-stuart-wakefield-and-betty-barnes)

Comment: Hello stuart! Thanks so much I updated the code and it works perfectly! Thanks so much! Really. God bless mate. And by the way, can you give me some tutorials in jQuery? the ones that are easy to follow. And what should I learn first? jquery or javascript?

Comment: No probs, remember to accept the answer. If you learn at least the basics of JavaScript first you will understand and appreciate fully what jQuery is and what it does. http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript, http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at datejs.

http://www.datejs.com/

Library which extends Javascript date functionality.

Allows you do stuff like:-

```
// Add 2 months to Today
Date.today().add(2).months();
```

Which pretty much covers your requirement.

Comment: How about getting the input from the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add 2 months to your current date,

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 2);
```

Comment: I want to add 2 months to my end date.. How can I do that?

Comment: You will have to convert month name to its number using array and use it in above code